# a good list of nouns that are commonly used in class names?

Tags: coding-style

I'm talking about the secondary noun in a class name. Things like...

- Provider
- Factory
- Repository
- Controller

etc...

Is there a list that's well understood? Naming classes is important for future maintainability so I'm wondering if we can make it easier on ourselves by using names that are familiar and have common meaning.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents. Use names that are closer to the business that you are developing application for (Read [Ubiquitous language](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/132)). For technical artifacts/services stay closer to the names used in design patterns ([GoF](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/), [GRASP](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~gpollice/cs4233-a05/CourseNotes/maps/class4/GRASPpatterns.html), [Core Patterns](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/)).